# Some 2.1/2.2 apps not working

Tags: 2.2-froyo, updates, compatibility

I just upgraded my Galaxy gt i5800 to 2.2 froyo from the kies firmware.
Why am I getting "not compatible with this device" from some apps that say they require 2.1 or 2.2? Can anyone please explain.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the apps that are listed as incompatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Not compatible with this device" message encompasses more than just the OS version.  The Play Store also checks for other software and hardware components that the app's developer listed as requirements.  These components can range from a minimum screen resolution, to having particular hardware (e.g. Tegra 3 chipset).

You can try searching for a given app on Google Play Store [website](https://play.google.com/store/apps) to get a better idea of the incompatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the advise probably screen res whats the problem. 1 thing i dont understand zynga poker wont dowmload through google play says not compatible it used to load and has loaded from another source? Thanks for the advise it it worth doing the rom upgrade (to overclock etc.)  or should i just stay with the samsung firmware via kies.